# Piping stdout to two different commands

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, pipe, tee

Been working on this all day, kind of got it to run, but I may still need some help to polish my code language.

**Situation:** I am using *bedtools* that gets two files (tab delimited) that contain genomic intervals (one per line) with some additional data (by column). More precisely, I am running the *window* function, this generates and output that contains for each interval in "a" file, all the intervals in "b" file that fall into the window that I have defined with parameter `-l` and `-r`. More precise explanation can be found [here](http://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/window.html).

An example of function as taken from their web:

```
$ cat A.bed
chr1  1000  2000

$ cat B.bed
chr1  500   800
chr1  10000 20000

$ bedtools window -a A.bed -b B.bed -l 200 -r 20000
chr1  1000   2000  chr1  10000  20000

$ bedtools window -a A.bed -b B.bed -l 300 -r 20000
chr1  1000   2000  chr1  500    800
chr1  1000   2000  chr1  10000  20000
```

**Question:** So the thing is that I want to use that *stdout* to do a number of things in one shot.

1. Count the number of lines in the original stdout. For that I use `wc -l`
2. Then:

   - cut columns 4-6 `cut -f 4-6`
   - sort lines and keep only those not repeated `sort | uniq -u`
   - save to a file `tee file.bed`
   - count number of lines of the new stdout, again `wc -l`

So I have manged to get it to work more or less with this:

```
windowBed -a ARS_saccer3.bed -b ./Peaks/WTappeaks_-Mit_sorted.bed -r 0 -l 10000 | tee >(wc -l) >(cut -f 7-13 | sort | uniq -u | tee ./Window/windowBed_UP10.bed | wc -l)
```

This kind of works, because I get the output file correctly, and the values show in screen but... like this

```
juan@juan-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/sf_Biolinux_sf/IGV/Collisions$ 448
543
```

The first number is the second `wc -l` I don't understand why it shows first. And also, after the second number, cursor remains awaiting for instructions instead of appearing a new command line, so I assume there is something that remain unfinished with the code line as it is right now. 
This probably is something very basic, but I will be very grateful to anyone that cares to explain me a little more about programming.
For anyone willing to offer solutions, bear in mind that I would like to keep this pipe in one line, without the need to run additional sh or anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you create a "forked pipeline" like this, bash has to run the two halves of the fork concurrently, otherwise where would it buffer the stdout for the other half of the fork? So it is essentially like running both subshells in the background, which explains why you get the results in an order you did not expect (due to the concurrency) and why the output is dumped unceremoniously on top of your command prompt.

You can avoid both of these problems by writing the two outputs to separate temporary files, waiting for everything to finish, and then concatenating the temporary files in the order you expect, like this:

```
windowBed -a ARS_saccer3.bed -b ./Peaks/WTappeaks_-Mit_sorted.bed -r 0 -l 10000 | tee >(wc -l >tmp1) >(cut -f 7-13 | sort | uniq -u | tee ./Window/windowBed_UP10.bed | wc -l >tmp2)
wait
cat tmp1 tmp2
rm tmp1 tmp2
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding where this is documented, but I thought that `wait` would only one process substitution (the most recent one?) was included in the set of processes `wait` would wait for.

Comment: "u.  Bash now allows waiting for the most recent process substitution, since it
    appears as $!." (from the release notes for 4.4)